# Mutually exclusive args

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

Is it possible to set mutually exclusive args? like:

```gql
type Query {
  listings (sellerId: ID! | landlordId: ID!): [Listing]
}
```

I know that I can let both args as optional:

```gql
type Query {
  listings (sellerId: ID, landlordId: ID): [Listing]
}
```

But that's not what I want, I want the client to necessarily pass either `sellerId` or `landlordId`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Normally I check for this in the query's resolver code. I don't think it can be done directly in the query definition. It might be possible by defining an `input type` that is the `union` of two other types but I'm not sure one can do that.